# Google SWIFFY not working in IE9 - Script Error 'runtime.js'

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-canvas, google-swiffy

I converted my SWF to HTML5 using Google's SWIFFY. THis works fine on FF and other Browsers, however I get an Error in IE9. Weird, cause the Google release page says it supports IE9.

Is there a way of getting around this?

I was thinking of doing a fallback to SWF Flash Player for IE Only. Also not sure how to do this. If anyone can help me to solve this problem that would be great.
Much Appreciated!!!

Here's the Code from the HTML5 File (Standard to all other SWIFFY HTML Files):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Swiffy output</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.3/runtime.js"></script>
    <script>
          swiffyobject = {"internedStrings": [
           "::::::::","::::::6Y:","::::::7E:","::::::9S:","RrRrRr::","::::::5H:","::::::8B:",
           "::::::1Q:","::::::8L:","::::::2N:","::::::8V:","::::::4K:","DdDdDd::",
           "5C5c5C5c5C5c::","::::::0J................................    
     </script>
     <style>html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%}</style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
    <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 711px; height: 661px">
    </div>
    <script>

      var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
                                   swiffyobject);

      stage.start();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's docs actually currently claim that support is only IE10+.

To use a flash fallback I would simply use IE conditional comments. Only include the swiffy javascript if the browser is IE10+ (`<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->` ... `<!--<![endif]-->`), and fallback to embedding the SWF files directly by wrapping their HTML in `<!--[if lte IE 9]>` ... `<![endif]-->`.